# PGAdmin3 hidden object types

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have scoured the web and PGSQL docs for information on what, to me, is a hidden data type, but have come up short. I am working on an existing database that has functions with return types with preceding double underscores (__some_type). In PGAdmin3, you can optionally display types in your tree view, there I see some recognizable types that are used in various functions and what not, but nowhere do I see these other types. I learned, through PyCharm Full edition, I can connect to a PostgreSQL DB and see all of the types I mention. As well as in the console with "\dT", but not in PGAdmin itself.

> Question: What is the deal with types that are preceded with one or two underscores? (__some_type).

Followup: I did find an unverified source describe a convention that restricts users from creating types that start with an underscore, but have not confirmed this from PG sources.

Here is the link to that: https://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/aw_pgsql_book/node223.html

And the line I mention is all the way towards the bottom under "NOTES":

> Type names cannot begin with the underscore character ("_") and can
>   only be 31 characters long. This is because Postgres silently creates
>   an array type for each base type with a name consisting of the base
>   type's name prepended with an underscore.

**Continued searching results:**
I have found references to what I speak of, but it does not go into detail about the behavior of such types, or what happens if users violate this 'restriction'.

PG Source from 6.3 docs:

> As discussed earlier, Postgres fully supports arrays of base types.
>   Additionally, Postgres supports arrays of user-defined types as well.
>   When you define a type, Postgres automatically provides support for
>   arrays of that type. For historical reasons, the array type has the
>   same name as the user-defined type with the underscore character _
>   prepended. Composite types do not need any function defined on them,
>   since the system already understands what they look like inside.

[6.4 Docs on Create Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/6.4/static/sql-createtype.htm):

> Restrictions
>
> Type names cannot begin with the underscore character ("_") and can
>   only be 15 characters long. This is because Postgres silently creates
>   an array type for each base type with a name consisting of the base
>   type's name prepended with an underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restriction on underscores in type names no longer applies. Judging by the docs, it was dropped between [8.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createtype.html#SQL-CREATETYPE-NOTES) and [8.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-createtype.html#SQL-CREATETYPE-NOTES).

The fact that these types don't show up in pgAdmin3 looks like a bug. As you can see from the [source](https://github.com/postgres/pgadmin3/blob/794527d97e2e3b01399954f3b79c8e2585b908dd/pgadmin/schema/pgType.cpp#L463), it filters out any type with a leading underscore. It's trying to suppress the auto-generated array types, but the query predates release 8.3 (back when this was still a reliable approach), and was never updated to use the new `pg_type.typarray` column.

Not sure if this issue is present in pgAdmin4. If you want to stick with pgAdmin3, BigSQL are still maintaining a [fork](https://www.openscg.com/bigsql/pgadmin3/), so they're probably your best bet if you want to see this fixed.

Comment: I thank you! I did eventually read all the different documentations from 6.3 to 9.x and you are correct.